# Python is ignoring subprocess

Tags: python, apache, flask, subprocess

I have a flask application where a user uploads a file and enters in text which is transmitted back to the flask app and used to exectute linux commands for the "aptly" program.

This is the relevant code:

```
repoName = request.form['repoName']
completePath = packageDir + filename

subprocess.call(["aptly", "repo", "add", repoName, completePath])
```

When I return either `repoName` or `completePath` it returns the correct information, but that subprocess.call is just completely ignored and I have no idea why. There's no errors/traceback  except for apache giving me back a log from the `aptly` command about proper usage, like so:

```
Usage: aptly repo add <name> <package file.deb>|<directory> ...

aptly repo add - add packages to local repository


Options:
  -architectures="": list of architectures to consider during (comma-separated), default         to all available
  -config="": location of configuration file (default locations are /etc/aptly.conf, ~/.aptly.conf)
  -dep-follow-all-variants=false: when processing dependencies, follow a & b if depdency is 'a|b'
  -dep-follow-recommends=false: when processing dependencies, follow Recommends
  -dep-follow-source=false: when processing dependencies, follow from binary to Source packages
  -dep-follow-suggests=false: when processing dependencies, follow Suggests
  -remove-files=false: remove files that have been imported successfully into repository
```

Any help would be much appreciated :(

EDIT:

Here's what the interpreter outputs, same commands but something actually happens this way...:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> repoName = "FSW"
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["aptly", "repo", "show", repoName]) 
'Name: FSW\nComment: \nDefault Distribution: \nDefault Component: main\nNumber of packages: 0\n'
>>> subprocess.call(["aptly", "repo", "show", repoName])
Name: FSW
Comment: 
Default Distribution: 
Default Component: main
Number of packages: 0
0
>>> package="/var/www/aptlyapp/app/tmp/vlc_2.0.3-5_amd64.deb"
>>> subprocess.check_output(["aptly", "repo", "add", repoName, package])
'Loading packages...\n[+] vlc_2.0.3-5_amd64 added\n'
>>>
```

For some reason that works just fine...

Comment: Could you print the value of `completePath`. Maybe you need to use `os.path.join(packageDir, filename)` to make sure proper path separators are used.

Comment: Yea that is being done on packageDir, doing packageDir + filename gives me "/var/www/aptlyapp/app/tmp/vlc_2.0.3-5_amd64.deb" so I don't think that's the issue

Comment: I often log the full command before calling a subprocess. It often help debugging. What is the full command? `' '.join(["aptly", "repo", "add", repoName, completePath])`

Comment: Full command is "aptly repo add repoName completePath", or aptly repo add "name" "file". What did you mean with the .join?

Comment: Just have the actual string that could be used in a terminal. The join will create a string from a list using ' ' a delimiter between each list entry.